# multiple file processing using ADF

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-data-lake, u-sql

I have created pipeline which does steps

1. Copy files from azure blob storage and save in Azure data lake store then
2. Then USql task pick that files and create summarize files in azure data lake store
3. Next task pick data from that file and save in db

I am passing 2 parameters windowStart and windowEnd and giving date ranage. Issue is it is always process 1 day not sure what is the problem

- Note initially i created copy task with tumbling window trigger that copied all files from blob to ADLStore but once i added new tasks and running manually it is processing only one file.

Thanks